# how to write a loops within a loop in GAMS

Tags: loops, gams-math

I have a deterministic model and I want to run my model several times each time changing two parameters `Var1` and `Var2`in order to see how they affect the results.
I can summarize my model like this:

```
...
equations obj,a,b;

obj...  Ax+By=e=cost;
a...    x+y=l=var1 * z1;
b...    x+y=l=var2 * z2;

solve;
dispaly cost.l;
dispaly y.l;
dispaly x.l;
```

Where x,y are variables, var1, z1, var2, and  z2 are parameters. I want to try 10 different values for var1 and 10 different values for var2 and have the results.

Could please tell me what is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can check [here](http://www.gams.com/mccarl/mccarlhtml/index.html?loop.htm) how to use loop statement.

In your case you have to define a set i of 10 values and two parameters var1_values(i), var2_values(i).

In your loop you have to include

```
var1 = var1_values(i);
var2 = var2_values(i);
solve;
*you can also store values to new parameters
display cost.l;
display y.l;
display x.l;
```

but not the equations. You have probably omitted information from solve statement on purpose but you have to specify which model to solve and whether you want to minimize or maximize a variable (in this case probably obj). If you don't specify this, GAMS finds just a feasible solution which will not be unique in your model.